# Function getSelectionFinalTotalPrice, Bundle price update

Tags: magento-1.9, price, bundled-product

Goodnight,
I updated the model Price.phtml that handles the prices of the bundled products.
My need is to add a surplus price on regular prices based on a custom attribute (supplementoprezzo). The bundle is Dynamic.
This is the function interested:

```
public function getSelectionFinalTotalPrice ($bundleProduct, $selectionProduct, $bundleQty, $selectionQty, $multiplyQty = true, $takeTierPrice = true)
{

$attribute = $bundleProduct->getResource()->getAttribute('supplementoprezzo');
$supplementoprezzo = $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($bundleProduct); 

if (is_null($selectionQty)) {
    $selectionQty = $selectionProduct->getSelectionQty();
}

if ($bundleProduct->getPriceType() == self::PRICE_TYPE_DYNAMIC) {

    $price = $selectionProduct->getFinalPrice($takeTierPrice ? $selectionQty : 1);

} else {
    if ($selectionProduct->getSelectionPriceType()) { // percent
        $product = clone $bundleProduct;
        $product->setFinalPrice($this->getPrice($product));
        Mage::dispatchEvent(
            'catalog_product_get_final_price',
            array('product' => $product, 'qty' => $bundleQty)
        );
        $price = ($product->getData('final_price')) * ($selectionProduct->getSelectionPriceValue() / 100);



    } else { // fixed
        $price = $selectionProduct->getSelectionPriceValue();
    }
}
$price = $this->getLowestPrice($bundleProduct, $price, $bundleQty);

if ($multiplyQty) {
    $price *= $selectionQty;
}

$price += $supplementoprezzo;
return $price;
}
```

The last two lines are the lines affected: the variable $supplementoprezzo is a float number.
The problem (and the odd thing) is that if I enter a number like this:

```
$price += 2.50;
return $price;
```

everythink works like a charme..
Instead summing the variable (which also is a number)

```
$price += $supplementoprezzo;
return $price;
```

the final price of the bundle is not updated with the surplus value.
I tried with various casting for the variable (float, floatval number_format, etc) .... nothing.
Any suggestions?

Thank you

Save

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,
the problem was that retrivieng attribute "supplementoprezzo" this way:

```
$attribute = $bundleProduct->getResource()->getAttribute('supplementoprezzo');
$supplementoprezzo = $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($bundleProduct);
```

was not recognized in cart controller.

This is the right way:

```
$productId = $bundleProduct->getId();
$bundleProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$supplementoprezzo =  $bundleProduct->getData('supplementoprezzo');
$_bcbbMaxQty =  $bundleProduct->getData('bcbb_maximum_qty');
$supplementoprezzo = ($supplementoprezzo/$_bcbbMaxQty);
$supplementoprezzo = number_format($supplementoprezzo, 2, '.', '');
```

Then this at the end made the magic:

```
if ($supplementoprezzo>0) {
    $price = $supplementoprezzo + $price;
    $selectionProduct->setCustomPrice($price);
    $selectionProduct->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
}
```